# React Firebase database

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, environment-variables

I'm trying to configure firebase config file like this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import Rebase from 're-base';

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID,
    appId: "some App Id"
};

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const base = Rebase.createClass(app.database());

export { base };
```

I also added a .env in the same level as node_modules is:

```
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY="my key"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN="my domain"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE="hmy db"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID="my project id"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET="";
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID="sender id"
```

And i've got an error:
TypeError: app.database is not a function .  << which is from firebase config. Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this `import 'firebase/database';`

Comment: Because you just importing the App service with ""firebase/app""  and not the whole Firebase package. You can find more informations here https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase